# What aren't my checkboxes responding individually?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

So the issue I am having is that my checkboxes in my JS game isn't responding to individual clicks. When I console.log, I get index 0 every time, no matter which box I click and a non responsive check box. However, the level functions are responding.

```js
    window.onload = function() {

      console.log('DOM is loaded');
      fillAll = function() {
        // event.preventDefault();
        for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
          document.bulbform.elements[i].checked = 1;
        }
      };

      clearAll = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
          document.bulbform.elements[i].checked = 0;
        }
      };

      levelOne = function() {
        clearAll();
        document.bulbform.elements[10].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[12].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[14].checked = 1;
      };

      levelTwo = function() {
        clearAll();
        document.bulbform.elements[12].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[16].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[17].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[18].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[20].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[21].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[22].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[23].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[24].checked = 1;
      };

      levelThree = function() {
        fillAll();
        document.bulbform.elements[4].checked = 0;
        document.bulbform.elements[6].checked = 0;
        document.bulbform.elements[7].checked = 0;
        document.bulbform.elements[8].checked = 0;
        document.bulbform.elements[11].checked = 0;
        document.bulbform.elements[12].checked = 0;
        document.bulbform.elements[13].checked = 0;
        document.bulbform.elements[16].checked = 0;
        document.bulbform.elements[17].checked = 0;
        document.bulbform.elements[18].checked = 0;
        document.bulbform.elements[24].checked = 0;
      };

      levelFour = function() {
        clearAll();
        document.bulbform.elements[2].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[6].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[8].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[10].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[12].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[14].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[16].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[18].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[22].checked = 1;
      };

      levelFive = function() {
        clearAll();
        document.bulbform.elements[11].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[16].checked = 1;
        document.bulbform.elements[21].checked = 1;
      };

      checkAll = function() {
        var win = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
          if (document.bulbform.elements[i].checked == 1) {
            win = 0;
          }
        }
        if (win == 1) {
          alert("You Won!");
        }
      };

      check = function(v) {
        a = parseInt(v);
        // console.log(parseInt(a));
        // console.log(typeof(a));

        if (document.bulbform.elements[v].checked == 1) {
          document.bulbform.elements[v].checked = 0;
        } else {
          document.bulbform.elements[v].checked = 1;
        }
        checkAll();
      };
    };
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="card-panel blue-grey lighten-3">
        <form name="bulbform">
          <!-- Row One -->
          <input type="checkbox" value="0" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>

          <!-- Row Two -->
          <input type="checkbox" value="5" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="6" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="7" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="8" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="9" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>

          <!-- Row Three -->
          <input type="checkbox" value="10" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="11" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="12" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="13" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="14" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>

          <!-- Row Four -->
          <input type="checkbox" value="15" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="16" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="17" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="18" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="19" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>

          <!-- Row Five -->
          <input type="checkbox" value="20" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="21" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="22" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="23" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="24" onclick="javascript:check(value)" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="1" />
          <label for="filled-in-box"></label>
          <br>
          <!-- Stat Game Levels -->
          <a href="javascript:levelOne()" class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat">Level 1</a>
          <a href="javascript:levelTwo()" class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat">Level 2</a>
          <a href="javascript:levelThree()" class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat">Level 3</a>
          <a href="javascript:levelFour()" class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat">Level 4</a>
          <a href="javascript:levelFive()" class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat">Level 5</a>
          <!-- End Game Levels -->
          <br>
          <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large" type="reset" value="clear" name="action">Clear
            <i class="material-icons left">lightbulb_outline</i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Would you tell me what is document.lightsform object?

Comment: Sure, this is for `<form name="lightsform">` in the html.

Comment: *checked* is boolean, set it to true or false (though assigning 0 or 1 will be type converted, it's just clearer to use a boolean). Also, don't use `javascript:` for inline handlers, they are javascript by default.

Answer (score 2):

Dai has good advice, but your actual issue is here:

```
... onclick="javascript:check(value)" ...
```

There no global *value* variable so you're passing *undefined*, which evaluates to 0. What you actually want to pass is the value of the checkbox:

```
... onclick="javascript:check(this.value) ...
```

Oh, also:

> checkboxes in my JS game isn't responding to individual clicks

because you're doing:

```
if (document.bulbform.elements[v].checked == 1) {
  document.bulbform.elements[v].checked = 0;
} else {
  document.bulbform.elements[v].checked = 1;
}
```

So if the checkbox is unchecked and then clicks on it, it's state in the listener is checked, so you uncheck it again. And *vice versa* if it's checked (the user clicks, unchecks it, then the listener checks it again). This is nonsensical, just remove the listener and let the checkbox be a checkbox by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong I guess. 
1) by default you have your checkbox clicked true
2) On clicking the checkbox,it turn to false but your code has

`if (document.bulbform.elements[v].checked == 1) {
          document.bulbform.elements[v].checked = 0;
        } else {
          document.bulbform.elements[v].checked = 1;
        }`

which turn the checkbox again to true. So whenever you try to click the checkbox, checked will return false as its state changes, and ur code changes that changed to true again

Remove the above code from your code. It will work fine.